# Can not install eros successfully

Tags: robotic-arm

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hello,I want to cross-compile ROS for ARM.I am trying to use eros according to http://wiki.ros.org/eros/Installation. When I run `$ rosinstall /opt/ros eros_diamondback.rosinstall`       It shows：ERROR in config：Is not a local file,nor a valid URL [eros_diamondback.rosinstall]:unknown url type:eros_diamondback.rosinstall

```
svn co https://code.ros.org/svn/eros/tags/diamondback ./eros
```

It also can not install successfully . Is the eros discarded?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/205834/can-not-install-eros-successfully/) by [Alice63](https://answers.ros.org/users/19628/alice63/) on ROS Answers with karma: 63 on 2015-03-24

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

The eros project has long since been abandoned, and ROS DiamondBack has been EOL for many years now.

Depending on your platform, you have several options to use ROS on ARM devices: you could follow the [indigo/Installation/UbuntuARM](http://wiki.ros.org/indigo/Installation/UbuntuARM) install guide, or the [BeagleBone](http://wiki.ros.org/BeagleBone) and/or the [bmwcarit/meta-ros](https://github.com/bmwcarit/meta-ros) (using OpenEmbedded) or attempt a from-source cross-compile yourself.

If at all possible, I'd use the pre-built debians and Ubuntu for ARM, as it reduces the effort required to get ROS on ARM significantly. Of course, whether you can do this depends on your actual hardware.

---

Originally posted by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) with karma: 86574 on 2015-03-25

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0